# ReactJS syntax error: unexpected token '<'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, babeljs, jsx, unexpected-token

I was following a course on udemy on react components and I was met with this
[Syntax error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2TuUy.png).

I have the following dependencies installed using yarn: 
   "dependencies": {
    "babel-preset-env": "1.5.2",
    "babel-preset-react": "6.24.1"
    }

Here's myJSX file:

```js
class Header extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return <p>This is from header</p>;
    }
}

const jsx = (
    <div>
        <h1>Title</h1>
        <Header />
    </div>
);


ReactDOM.render(jsx, document.getElementById('app'));
```

I am using this command to convert this to the main JS file:

```
babel src/app.js --out-file=public/scripts/app.js --preset=env,react --watch
```

Please let me Know what I am doing wrong here

Comment: Error messages are made up of text, show us error messages, not pictures of them.

Comment: What is that error message the output from anyway?

Comment: Don't you need to separately add JSX support? Your snippet works in JSFiddle when creating a React + JSX fiddle

Comment: Theres no error in this code, see this https://codepen.io/FederalCircle/pen/aKBXor, this is probably something with babel

Comment: @AlysonMaia Is there any other dependency I need to add?

Comment: @Leite JSX is supported out of the box with react preset.

Comment: @Ayankashyap have you tried updating your babel command yet ?

Comment: @user3210641 yeah It worked, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not 100% that this helps, but as stated in [babel docs](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/preset-react/) you should use `presets` instead of `preset`

```
babel script.js --presets react
```

So your full babel command:

```
babel src/app.js --out-file public/scripts/app.js --presets env,react --watch
```

Comment: Glad it helped ! :) Don't forget to accept this answer for people who might come to this thread in the future.